# Entire functions that satisfy certain equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following problem:

Let $f$ and $g$ be entire functions satisfying the equation $f^n(z) +g^n(z) = 1$ for all $z \in\mathbb{C}$, where $n \ge 2,\; n \in\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that if $g$ has no zeros, then both $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(z)$ is never zero, then $f(z)$ can never be an $n$-th root of unity.
What theorem might prevent an entire function from ever being an $n$-th root of unity?

Comment: Tthe theorem of isolated points?

Comment: @aymen A bigger theorem than that surely!

Comment: Liouville theorem?

Comment: @aymen: How many values does a non-constant entire function attain?

Comment: we have : If $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an entire, non-constant function with only finitely many zeros, then either $|f(z)|\rightarrow \infty$ for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ or there is a sequence of points $z_n$ such that $|z_n|\rightarrow\infty$ and $f(z_n)\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is never 0, $f$ avoids $n$ values. But the (small) Picard theorem tells you that an entire function which avoids 2 values is constant

Comment: I didn't understand how to prove that If $g$ is never 0, then  $f$ avoids $n$ values?

Answer (score 1):

$g^n(z)=1-f^n(z)$. As $g$ has no zero , $g(z)\not =0$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$ implies $g^n(z)\not =0$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. So $f^n(z) \not=1$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$. So $f$ omits the values of $n-th$ roots of unity. then by [Picards Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) $f$ is constant. Then $g$ is also constant.

Comment: I have an other question: Is this
conclusion true if $f$ and $g$ are allowed to have zeros?

Comment: No..........................

Comment: How to prove that?

Comment: It is too simple ..Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the follow-up where we look for entire $f$ and $g$ with $f^n+g^n=1$. I contend there are no non-constant **meromorphic** functions on $\Bbb C$ with $f^n+g^n=1$ for any $n\ge3$.

Consider the Riemann surface $S_n$ corresponding to the algebraic equation
$w^n+z^n=1$. This is the nonsingular curve in $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb C)$ defined
by an algebraic equation $X^n+Y^n=Z^n$. If $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic with $f^n+g^n=1$ they define a holomorphic map $F:\Bbb C\to S_n$.

Now $S_n$ has genus $\frac12(n-1)(n-2)\ge1$. By the uniformisation theorem its
universal covering can be taken to be $D$, the unit disc. As $\Bbb C$ is
simply connected, $F$ lifts to a holomorphic map to the universal covering of $S_n$, that is a holomorphic map $\Bbb C\to D$. By Liouville, this is constant. So $F$ is constant, and $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Comment: Your argument does not work for n=2, whereas the proposition is still correct

Comment: @Thomas I did write "$n\ge3$".

Comment: But the question is also raised for n=2

Comment: @Thomas Which question? aymen's "is the conclusion true if $f$ and $g$ are allowed to have zeros"? Well there are obvious examples when $n=2$ and it is not hard to prove a general form for them.

Comment: There is no example, as there is no entire function which avoid the values 1 and -1 . In order to promote your proof you should say that the map F would be with values in an elliptic curve with at least one point (g=0) removed.

Comment: @Thomas What have elliptic curves to do with this? Of course there are examples of entire $f$ and $g$ with $f^2+g^2=1$, for instance $f=\sin z$ and $g=\cos z$. I really didn't think I'd need to spell that out.

Comment: But sometines, $g=0$.....and by the way the curve $x^2+y^2=1$ is rational, not elliptic (sorry), and one need to remove three points the two at infinity and another one,  to get Liouville theorem

Comment: @Thomas As I said several comments back we are discussing the case where $f$ and $g$ can have zeros.